# IF statements causing long processing/send times for ~600k list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, automationstudio

I'm trying to trim some time off of our newsletter sends. We have a daily newsletter that delivers to ~600k subscribers each morning. The content is populated by an RSS feed that is parsed with AMPScript blocks containing numerous IF statements (example included below). The automation currently takes an average of 3+ hours to complete (including a 30 min wait period).

How can I be more efficient with my AMPScript and/or cache elements of the newsletter in order to speed up the automation's processing time?

Note: Each day's newsletter contains 9 - 12 of these blocks of AMPScript to parse different categories of the RSS feed (i.e. Page one, The Nation, etc). The `@xml` variable is set only once via `httpget()`, then used throughout the 9-12 blocks.

Any and all thoughts are appreciated! Thanks!

```
%%[

Var @xml, @title, @image, @link, @desc, @overline, @hide, @i, @rowCount, @Nodes, @none
Set @xml = TreatAsContentArea('RSSCA1',HTTPGet("My RSS url")) /* content area from which the RSS content will be pulled */
Set @Nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml, "//item[category='Page one']", 1)
Set @rowCount = rowcount(@Nodes)

for @i = 1 to 4 do

    if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/title"),1)) > 0 then
        set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/title"),1),1),'Value')
    elseif
        rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/title"),1)) < 1
    then
        set @none = ';display:none; mso-hide:all'
    endif

    if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/enclosure"),1)) > 0 then
        set @image = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/enclosure"),1),1),'url_att')
    else
        set @image = 'my backup image'
    endif

    if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/category[position()>1]"),1)) > 0 then
        set @overline = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/category[position()>1]"),1),1),'Value')
    else
        set @hide = ';display:none;mso-hide:all'
    endif

    if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/link"),1)) > 0 then
        set @link = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/link"),1),1),'Value')
    endif

    if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/description"),1)) > 0 then
        set @desc = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("//item[category='Page one'][",@i,"]/description"),1),1),'Value')
    endif
]%%

<tr>
<td class="two-column" style="padding:0;width:520px;max-width:520px;padding:20px 0;border-bottom:solid 1px #eaeaea %%=v(@none)=%%">
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <table width="520" align="center" style="padding:0;border-spacing:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="200" valign="top" style="max-width:200px;padding:0;border:0;">
  <![endif]-->
  <div class="narrow-column" style="width:38%;max-width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
    <table style="border-spacing:0 %%=v(@none)=%%">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:0;">
          <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;"><img class="image" src="%%=v(@image)=%%" width="200" style="border:0;width:100%;max-width:200px;"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  </td>
  <td width="305" valign="top" style="max-width:305px;padding:0;border:0;">
  <![endif]-->
  <div class="wide-column" style="width:58%;max-width:305px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
    <table style="border-spacing:0 %%=v(@none)=%%">
      <tr>
        <td class="text" style="padding:0;padding-left:15px;">
          <p class="overline" style="Margin:0;font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;line-height:12px;font-weight:normal;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:left;color:#870413%%=v(@hide)=%%"> %%=v(@overline)=%%
                                    </p>
          <p class="headline" style="Margin:0 0 5px 0;font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;line-height:28px;"><a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" target="_blank" class="headline-link" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;"> %%=v(@title)=%%</a>
          </p>

          <p class="copy" style="Margin:0;font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;">%%=v(@desc)=%%  <a class="continue" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:underline;color:#127694;"> Continue reading &rarr;</a>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>

%%[ NEXT @i ]%%
```

Update 5/10/17: I ended up "solving" the processing time issue by breaking the list into smaller segments, which sped up the time to send. Not a perfect solution by any means, but one that worked for our purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd look into off-loading the caching/parsing of the RSS data into a [**SSJS Script Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/) that writes it to a Data Extension.

Then in your email, you can just do a lookup and iterate through the rows, displaying the HTML for each one.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the suggestion. I'm sure this would work, unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with Server Side Java Script to implement the solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems pretty much all 600k subscribers get the same content. I see you're caching the HttpGet by using TreatAsContentArea, but you still have a large number of expensive operations that you're executing 600k times - BuildRowSetFromXML etc.

Take more or less the entirety of the above, place it in a Content Area and then call that Content Area from your email using TreatAsContentArea.

You should be able to send millions per hour that way.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the help! In the original version of this email I had a main template that called content areas based on the day of the week (each day has different sections/requirements). Each content area contained a version of the code above. For example: `if @pubDate == 'Mon' then
               set @content = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\TH RSS Blocks\TH RSS TEST Blocks\Monday TEST")` So if I wrap that ContentAreaByName function in a TreatAsContentArea(), would that do the trick?

Comment: Or do you mean when I call the content block with the `%%=v(@content)=%%` I should instead use `%%=TreatAsContentArea('CA' , v(@content))=%%` ?

Comment: Hey Jeff. Yes. Wrap that ContentAreaByName in a TreatAsContentArea() and you'll notice a marked improvement. I did similar with a client with similar volumes and time to send to you and ended up reducing 3.5 hours to 7 minutes. The email crashed their website with the spike in activity and the conversation moved to Send Throttling... LOL.

Comment: haha a far better problem to have! I'll do what you've suggested and report back. Any chance you know of a way to check time to send without, you know, actually sending a live email to 600k people...

Comment: Either of your formulations amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Testing time to send can be done to a a degree, I guess. Trouble is it'll cost you Super Messages and Contacts. Create a file with email addresses using the domain "bh.exacttarget.com" (blackhole domain maintained by SFMC). Make sure you don't use SubscriberKeys that collide with production ones or it'll send to genuine subscribers with those keys.

Comment: Sending to an email address like 12345@bh.exacttarget.com makes the OMM go through the whole process of sending and you can test performance of your message (largely). You'll be charged as though it was a genuine send, though, and those Contacts created through All Subscribers don't disappear automagically. Bear in mind when testing that OMM takes a while to "build" the email. The example I was talking about above involved a send to 700K subs. Build time was around 4 mins, so once sending it was actually sending at around 700K/3mins.